# Why does nexus repository response 502 Bad Gateway error?

Tags: package-management, 22.04, repository

I'm using nexus repository 3.37.3. I do as describe [here](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/apt-repositories). The apt repository is as follows:
[image]

The ubuntu's `source.list` file is as follows:

```
deb http://192.168.1.102:8081/repository/apt-jammy jammy main
```

But when I want to install `vim`, the result is as follows:

[image]

Why can not I download packages? What's the problem?

**Note**: The ubuntu version is 22.04

Comment: On your nexus box, directly, can you get a response from `curl -I http://archive.ubuntu.com/` ?  Does it return 502?  If not, then the issue is the Nexus Repository manager is trying to connect to the remote repository and is unable to reach the remote repositories, hence 502 Bad Gateway, I believe

Comment: @ThomasWard Nexus Server has access to `http://archive.ubuntu.com` and connection is not the problem.

Comment: Try to update Nexus repo, check for solution:
https://community.sonatype.com/t/apt-proxy-repo-for-ubuntu-2204-results-in-502-bad-gateway/8670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update your Nexus. See https://community.sonatype.com/t/apt-proxy-repo-for-ubuntu-2204-results-in-502-bad-gateway/8670